# Fetch in React adds localhost before the url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost, fetch, package.json

I'm using fetch to read some data with a GET request.

Something like this:

```
  fetch(
    'myurl.com/data',
    requestOptions
  )
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
```

I've tested it in postman and it works fine, it returns the data.

The problem is when I call it in browser, it returns an HTML instead of JSON.

In Dev Tools -> Network -> Initiator the url appears different, it adds at the beginning of it "localhost..."

Like this:  `http://localhost:3000/store/orders/myurl.com/data`. And because of this the url is broken and it doesn't return the JSON.

There is no `http://localhost:3000/store/orders` in the project, it is in **package.json** this line: `"homepage": "/store/orders/"`.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: what's the exact value for `myurl.com`?

Comment: use `http://myurl.com/data` no `myurl.com/data`

Comment: add `http://` or `https://` in front of the url

Answer (score 4):

Try not omitting the protocol part `http://`, so your fetch call will look like this:

```
 fetch(
    'http://myurl.com/data',
....
```

Comment: I added that part and it throws this error now: Access to fetch at 'http://myurl.com/data from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: yes, that is expected behavior (and a different question for you to research). 
To give you direction:

Comment: Options how to fix that: 
1. deploy your project, setup TLS and use https protocol
2. (testing)  add `myurl.com` to the trusted sources in your chrome browser settings 
3. (testing) hack CORS policy from server-side (myurl.com) temporary
This is another big question, do separate research...

Basically this is something that google chrome does for security.

Comment: I added in requestOptions: `mode: 'no-cors'` and that error doesn't appear anymore. Now it's only a short error message saying: net::ERR_ABORTED 400

Comment: check that the preflight OPTIONS request is successful (It is displayed in chrome developers tools network tab).

Comment: not sure. If you have access to the `tf-commerse-api...` it might help to check it's logs. Also, still may be cross-origin problem if `tf-commerse-api...` configured strictly.
Too much variables here. Try to break down the problem to smaller pieces. First try to load data from something that you have control of. Like a mock...